# Chrome Developer Tools Network close request details remember marked request

Tags: google-chrome, debugging, networking, request, jinitiator

I **inspect** a **xhr request** in chrome to **see** its **details** and check if this is the request I'm looking for. The **currently inspected request** is **marked** on the left list of requests.
If I want to see what code initiated this request, I **close** the **details** pane and **look for** the line that was **recently marked active** and check the initiator column.
The problem is every time I **close** the **details** pane, the **highlight** **from** the **active line gets removed** and I have to search for my recently inspected request.
Is there a way to keep this line marked or maybe directly show the initiator stack?

[image]
[image]